# Broadcasting to everyone except sender socket.io

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, socket.io, broadcast

I am building a chat in my app. I am using socket.io for this. When a user sends a message I send an api request to my server. The api stores the message in the database and only then emits, with a socket service to everyone in the room that there is a new message. I have a SocketService class with this method:

```
private async broadcast({ type, data, chatId, senderId }: { type: string; data: any; chatId: string; senderId: string }) {
    const excludedSocket = await this.getUserSocket(senderId);
    if (chatId && excludedSocket) {
      excludedSocket.emit;
    } else if (excludedSocket) {
      excludedSocket.emit(type, data);
    } else if (room) {
      gIo.to(room).emit(type, data);
    } else {
      gIo.emit(type, data);
    }
  }
```

The problem I have is that getUserSocket returns a RemoteSocket object that doesn't have the broadcast or methods on it. So how can I achieve this?

```
private async getUserSocket(userId: string) {
    const sockets = await this.getAllSockets();
    const socket = sockets.find((s) => s.data.uid === userId);
    return socket;
}

private async getAllSockets() {
    const sockets = await this.io.fetchSockets();
    return sockets
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`socket.broadcast.emit` equates to a [BroadcastOperator](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io/blob/129883958afcd1e8c34ca0dd3e42d40d92557afd/lib/broadcast-operator.ts#L14) that sends to an empty Set of rooms (meaning "all rooms"), excluding the socket id "room" of the sender Socket.

The same BroadcastOperator can be created from the server instance with [server.except()](https://socket.io/docs/v4/server-api/#serverexceptrooms)

```
const sockets = await this.io.except(socketIdString).emit('blah', x)
```

Comment: But i want to sned to a specific room, which is the chatId, and exclude only the sender. except ake a room as an argument, not a socket id

Comment: The code is `this.io.to(room).except(xroom).emit('blah', x)`. If you don't have a socket id to except then you need a room, or otherwise a way to lookup the id(s) you want to except.